# c# write to celery rabbitmq queue

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to write some c# script to write some data to celery queue that has been already created by my celery app (which I developed in Python). Whenever I try to send data to the celery queue the messages stuck under "Unacked" status, which doesn't happens whenever I write those same messages to another queue.

Here is my c# code that tries to write the messages to the celery queue under rabbitmq:

```js
public static void SendMessages(List < CeleryMessage > celeryMessages, string taskName) {
  ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory {
    HostName = CeleryHostName,
      UserName = "guest",
      Password = "guest",
      VirtualHost = "/"
  };

  using(IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
  using(IModel channel = connection.CreateModel()) {
    foreach(CeleryMessage celeryMessage in celeryMessages) {

      SendMessageSecondVersion(channel, celeryMessage, taskName);
      Console.WriteLine(" [X] Sent {0}", celeryMessage);
    }
  }
}

private static void SendMessageSecondVersion(IModel channel, CeleryMessage celeryMessage, string taskName) {
  var myDict = new Dictionary < string,
    string > ();
  myDict["id"] = "4cc7438e-afd4-4f8f-a2f3-f46567e7ca77";
  myDict["task"] = "celery.task.PingTask";
  myDict["args"] = "[]";
  myDict["kwargs"] = "{}";
  myDict["retries"] = "0";
  myDict["eta"] = "2009-11-17T12:30:56.527191";

  var result = string.Join(", ", myDict.Select(m => m.Key + ":" + m.Value).ToArray());
  var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
  channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "testcelery", routingKey: "testcelery", basicProperties: null, body: body);
}
```